# tcl how to split a string by using regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

I have some string with format

```
class(amber#good)
class(Back1#notgood)
class(back#good)
```

and I want to use regexp to get value of these string

Expected answer:

```
amber
Back1
back
```

And here's my cmd:

```
set string "class(amber#good)"
regexp -all {^\\([a-zA-z_0-9].\#$} $string $match
puts $match
```

But the answer is not what I expected

Comment: my option is to get the string which is beginning with "(" and end with "#"

Comment: Maybe just `regexp {\(([^()#]+)} $string - match`? See https://ideone.com/PmTaBW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
regexp {\(([^()#]+)} $string - match
```

See the [Tcl demo online](https://ideone.com/PmTaBW).

The `\(([^()#]+)` regex matches

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()#]+)` - Capturing group 1 (`match`): any one or more chars other than parentheses and `#`.

The hyphen is used since the whole-match value is not necessary, we are only interested to get Group 1 value.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes using regular expressions is error prone and/or overkill.

Here's an alternate answer using split:

`lindex [split $string "()#"] 1`